# Is there a way to send any SOAPHeader parameters when invoking a web method from the ASMX Help page?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I've implemented a new web service which uses SOAPExtensions for authentication. Everything works fine using a client that consumes this web service.

What I need to know is if there is a way to send any SOAPHeader parameters when invoking a web method from the ASMX Help page? I need this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this : 
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212839/testing-custom-soap-headers-in-asmx)

Comment: Thanks for this. I use SoapUI but you can't ask your customers to install a client app to test your web services before using, can you?

Comment: you're right.. but i think there is no options... you have to write a custom client and send to your customers...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a client application to test your service?

The client application can be a simple Console application, or it can be a unit test (even better).